# @aws-amplify/auth federatedSignUp function?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

With the npm package `@aws-amplify/auth` using react (`import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth'`), there are some exported functions such as `Auth.signUp({...})` and `Auth.federatedSignIn()`. The `federatedSignIn` sends users to the federated sign in endpoint with path `/login`. I would like to send them to `/signup` path but there is no such `federatedSignUp()` function, **anyone know a solution to send them to the `/signup` federated endpoint?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to just redirect user to the following URL:

```sh
https://${COGNITO_OAUTH_DOMAIN}/signup?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(COGNITO_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGN_IN_URL)}
```

Comment: looks like a solid answer so hell i'll just do this, I considered it but didn't know the scope of what I need to put in the url, thanks for clarifying this

Answer (score 0):

Using @jellycsc 's solution and expanding upon it (because I got unauthorized) here is what worked (I recommend anyone else go to their sign up url and copy it in manually and systematically replace values).

```
const baseUrl = `https://${aws.idpDomain}/signup`
const search = `?response_type=token&client_id=${aws.userPoolWebClientId}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
    aws.redirectSignIn
  )}&identity_provider=COGNITO&scope=email%20openid%20profile`

window.location.replace(baseUrl + search)
```